# I am travelling to Cancun with an Indian passport but I have a BRP (Biometric Residency Permit) with a leave to remain status

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, mexico, uk-residents

I am travelling to Cancun with an Indian passport and I have been raised in UK and I have a UK BRP (Biometric Residency Permit) with a leave to remain status. My flight has a stop over in Mexico for 3 hours. I was wondering what the visa process is or if I require visa to stay there for 1 week.

Comment: A LTR status? Do you mean **Indefinite** LTR (ILR)?